# Graphql error (Error: Expected {} to be a GraphQL schema.) when upgrading node 12 to node 18

Tags: graphql

[image][image][image]

I'm expecting to build proper graphql schema with no error above are the code screenshot. Below are the versions i have used.
graphql: 15.8.0
graphql-tools/stitch: 9.0.3
graphql-tools/wrap: 10.0.1
graphql-tools/executor-http: 1.0.7
graphql-tools/schema": 10.0.2
Provide some help from above error.